# Jmeter Groovy creating new list by iterting from previous list

Tags: groovy, jmeter

I have a list (tsts) which is dynamic and derived in separation operation but can look like below. 
I would like to iterate through tsts and create a new list --> list1, only picking up up to say up to index 2. I have tried the for loop and even--> tsts.eachWithIndex { item, index -> for some reason my list1 only contains the last item?

```
import org.apache.jmeter.util.JMeterUtils;
import groovy.json.JsonSlurper;
def jsonResponse = null;
List<String> tsts = new ArrayList<String>()
tsts = [10, 11, 12];
str1 = "abc"

def map1 = [:]
def list1 = []
int TCcntr = 2;
cnt1 = 0
System.out.println("1 My Loop begins----------------");
for(int i = 0;i<TCcntr;i++) {
    map1.clear()
    map1.put(str1,tsts[cnt1].toInteger());
    System.out.println("map1----> "+map1);
    // list1.add(map1);
    list1 = list1+map1;
    System.out.println("list---> "+list1);
    cnt1 = cnt1+1;
}
```

My output

```
1 My Loop begins----------------
map1----> [abc:10]
list---> [[abc:10]]
map1----> [abc:11]
list---> [[abc:11], [abc:11]]
```

why does list 1 keep picking up the last item iteration? it should look like this

```
   list1----> [[abc:10], [abc:11]]
```

Comment: Because of `list1 = list1+map1`.  You are accumulating up on that list inside the for.  This code looks very convoluted TBH. I'd guess that `def list1 = tsts.collect{ [abc: it ] }` would be enough for most of it.

Comment: Thanks but I only want up to index 1 with your code which I just tried I get : [[abc:10], [abc:11], [abc:12]]   I like up to index 1 or --> [[abc:10], [abc:11]]

Comment: Use `tsts.take(2).collect{ [abc: it ] }` then.

Comment: Thanks I Now get the first 2, what if I wanted say from index 1 to 2 how do I index ? With for loop you can easily pick which indexes you want and create a new list. take(2) picks only the first 2 .

Comment: Then you can use either `tail()` or `drop(1)` instead of `take(2)`

Answer (score 1):

This worked, Thanks to Dimitri and Tim, I also learned other methods

```
tsts = [10, 11, 12, 13];
str1 = "abc"
def list1 = []
int TCcntr = 3;

for(int i = 1;i<TCcntr;i++) {
    map1 =[:]
    map1.put(str1,tsts[i].toInteger());
    list1 = list1+map1;
}
```

output

```
 list---> [[abc:11], [abc:12]]
```

Comment: `def list1 = tsts.drop(1).take(2)*.toInteger().collect{ [abc: it] }`

Comment: Wow this one is really great, I love it, and it is elegant like others and works exactly how i want it